# php: max_input_vars exceeded 1000

Tags: php

I have 2 different web applications in 2 separate servers,
server 1 with "abc" web app has more than 2000 records in db, while server 2 with "123" web app has only 1000+ records.
But only "123" in server 2 comes with this warning:input variables exceeded 1000, do anyone know the reason? Thank first.
Is there any option to solve max_input_vars exceeded 1000 issue?
I ask because some people not recommended to change it in php.ini
And I believe my db records will keep increase in future, think that can't keep changing the number of max_input_vars right?

Comment: What does your code look like, or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: that page at least with 2 XHR to generate 2 dropdown list, each has 300 data. There is also window onload few functions too. Now I realized maybe this is my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have anything to do with DB record count, rather with what is the data size that you are sending to server.

Following is what manual says:

`How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request.`

If you do not want to update php.ini you can try using .htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```

Comment: thanks.
so mean that maybe my coding method caused too much data input?

Comment: is usually a server config related issue that coding related. Are you using suhosin or some secure installation?

Comment: ermm..I'm not sure what I am using..I am only use for upload files. I think is Centos, EPEL

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here
[PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit chan](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-unknown-input-variables-exceeded-1000-to-increase-the-limit-chan)

You can do it in .htaccess file using this:

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!